# LDAP configuration in wildfly, searching for roles

Tags: jboss, ldap, wildfly

I have Kerberos set up with wildfly plus I get groups from LDAP and it works for certain configurations but doesn't for others.

Kerberos works as expected and here is the config I have for LDAP:

```
<login-module code="org.jboss.security.negotiation.AdvancedLdapLoginModule" flag="requisite">
    <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url" value="ldap://ttttt.com:3268/"/>
    <module-option name="bindDN" value="user"/>
    <module-option name="bindCredential" value="passwd"/>
    <module-option name="baseCtxDN" value="DC=AD,DC=TTT,DC=com"/>
    <module-option name="baseFilter" value="(userPrincipalName={0})"/>
    <module-option name="rolesCtxDN" value="OU=Groups, DC=AD,DC=TTT,DC=com"/>
    <module-option name="roleFilter" value="(member={1})"/>
    <module-option name="roleAttributeID" value="memberOf"/>
    <module-option name="roleAttributeIsDN" value="true"/>
    <module-option name="roleNameAttributeID" value="cn"/>
    <module-option name="recurseRoles" value="true"/>
    <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
    <module-option name="allowEmptyPassword" value="false"/>
    <module-option name="searchScope" value="SUBTREE_SCOPE"/>
</login-module>
```

I have setup a group called app_ttt_api. I added some members to this group.

So my setup works when the member I added is a group itself and you are a member of that group. If you add a user directly, it doesn't work. Also if you add a group that contains a group that contains a user it also doesn't work.

So, `group->group->user` works but

```
group->user
```

and

```
group->group->group->user
```

doesn't

So I am trying to figure out what's wrong and what I should modify so if the user is part of any recursive groups or directly a part of group it should work.

Edit: subsequent question - can I see what LDAP actually returns in the log, i.e. the list of user groups the user belongs to? Or LDAP traffic?

Edit2: actually figured out the debugging, it's described here - https://developer.jboss.org/thread/272926

Edit3:

I looked at the source code of AdvancedLdapLoginModule

here: [AdvancedLdapLoginModule](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.jboss.security/jboss-negotiation-extras/2.1.0.GA/org/jboss/security/negotiation/AdvancedLdapLoginModule.java#AdvancedLdapLoginModule.rolesSearch%28javax.naming.ldap.LdapContext%2Cjava.lang.String%29)

From the code it looks like following:
1. get all the roles from initial role context filtering by user

```
526            results = searchContext.search(rolesCtxDN, roleFilter, filterArgs, roleSearchControls);
rolesCtxDN=DC=AD,DC=TTT,DC=com roleFilter=(member={1}) filterArgs[0]=myuser@AD.TTT.COM filterArgs[1]=CN=myuser,CN=Managed Service Accounts,DC=AD,DC=MLP,DC=com
```

2. Iterate through roles calling

   532 obtainRole(searchContext, resultDN);
3. In obtainRole it calls

   572      Attributes result = searchContext.getAttributes(dn, attrNames);
   575         Attribute roles = result.get(roleAttributeID);

   where attrNames is roleAttributeID - "memberOf" in my case.
4. Go through all the roles obtained from line 575 and call

   585 loadRoleByRoleNameAttributeID(searchContext, roleDN);
   586 recurseRolesSearch(searchContext, baseRoleDN);

where 585 adds a role and 586 recursively searches for underlying roles.

The problem in my case in 3 - why would we try to get roles our initial role is memberOf and not add it right away, we already know that the user is a member of this role. I think that's the reason why I only get authorized when I have group->group->user and not in other cases.

Am I understanding what's going on right? Should I pass something else in the config? I tried different variations of the config, when I do

```
   <module-option name="roleAttributeID" value="cn"/>
   <module-option name="roleAttributeIsDN" value="false"/>
```

it will load all first level roles, but wouldn't recurse to lower level groups.

In other configurations I tried there were no roles loaded.